# Detect if client is iPhone, if so display a specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm tuning the mobile view of my website and I was wondering, if there a way to detect if client is an iPhone, and if so display `<div id="iphone-bar"></div>` ?

Can't find a way to do this...

Comment: Check the user agent string and if it's an iPhone show your div, only iPhone or mobile at all? Check this: http://detectmobilebrowsers.com

Answer (score 2):

You can check your `user agent` string:

> Returns the user agent string for the current browser.

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorID.userAgent

Like:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad)/)) {
   $('#iphone-bar').show();
}
```

If you want to check mobile browsers in general use http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/ and get the regexp to match them.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<script>
var iPhone= ( navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone)/g) ? true : false );

if( iPhone ) {
    document.getElementById('iphone-bar').style.display = 'block'
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
 function isiPhone() {
    return (navigator.platform.indexOf("iPhone") != -1);
}
```

Then, use it as below:

```
if(isiPhone()) {
   //handle iPhone code
}
```